# Is it worth switching from NTFS to ZFS or Btrfs to prevent silent data corruption?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

I have 4 external hard drives.
Two of them are formatted to ext4 because I was a linux user, and the rest two to NTFS.

I read somewhere that data on hard drives would be corrupted before we knew it,
and that filesystems with checksumming let us know if some data on the source drive were corrupted.

So I plan to get rid of windows and return to Linux only for that checksumming filesystem.
I'm not interested in RAID or any other advanced tequnique as of now.

Should I return to Linux to avoid bit rot?
or is bit rot so rare that we need not care about it?

Which is better, ZFS or Btrfs?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure it is a real problem on a good hard drive. I have a ThinkPad 10 years old and nothing has been lost on the hard drive. I had clients with lots of computers and "bit rot" was not an issue on these computers either.

Comment: Detecting the problem is only one part of the equation. You also need backups to restore from. Even in-filesystem redundancy is not enough.

Comment: On Windows you can use ReFS which has the same checksum feature as ZFS or Btrfs. Anyway both ZFS and Btrfs also have good drivers for Windows, unlike the ext4 driver which is still terrible after decades

Comment: Read everywhere how they lost btrfs and zfs despite its "robustenss". Checksums by itself doesnt help. You need redundancy multidisk setup. And btrfs implements multidevice redundancy badly and in unpredictible way. zfs multidevice and selfhealing is more matured

Comment: Example whats wrong with btrfs https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/examining-btrfs-linuxs-perpetually-half-finished-filesystem/